# Mongoose for var in loop in subdocuments

Tags: node.js, mongodb, for-loop, mongoose, subdocument

I created this schema with `mongoose Schema` :

```
socialAccount =  new Schema({
    socialNetwork : { type : String , required : true},
    userid : { type : Number,  required :  true },
    username : String
},{_id : false});
person = new Schema({
    id : { type : Number,  unique : true, required : true , dropDups :  true },
    firstname : String,
    lastname : String,
    socialAccounts : [socialAccount],
    updated : { type : Date, default : Date.now },
    enable : { type : Boolean , default : true },       
});
```

When i get data with `findOne` method the result looks like this (in `console.log()`) :

```
{ 
  id: 1,
  firstname: 'example name',
  lastname: 'example last',
  enable: true,
  updated: Thu Sep 24 2015 09:40:17 GMT+0330 (IRST),
  socialAccounts: 
   [ { socialNetwork: 'instagram',
       userid: 1234567,
       username: 'example' } ] }
```

SO, When i want to iterate on subdocument `socialAccounts` with `for var in` loop structure & view data with `console.log()`, it returns some other objects & function & only the first one is subdocument object.
How can i get only first element of `socialAccounts` subdocument with this for-loop iterate method.

Thanks

Comment: I think `Person.findOne` returns a bson file and you might want to `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())` the document to make it an normal array object

Comment: Thanks, this way works too. but i think less code is better, so i want to use @qqilihq approach.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use an indexed `for` loop, instead of a `for` … `in`:

```
for (let i = 0; i < socialAccounts.length; i++) {
    var currentAccount = socialAccounts[i];
}
```

The `for` … `in` loop will enumerate additional object properties as you noticed and should not be used for arrays. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-array-in-javascript) question and answers.

Comment: How would I enumerate over object properties with for ... in?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
.findOne(...() => {})
```

It worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Using ES6, you can iterate through the objects of array without the mess of handling the index and array access by using `let obj of arr`.

```
 for (let item of arr) {
  console.log(item)
 }
```